# Unable to run react native app in debug mode

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, npm

react-native run-android installs the release mode and not connecting with JS server in Ubuntu.Any solution?

"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "0.63.2",

Android SDK: 29

Comment: your question needs to be worded with more clarity. debug !== release and is your server pingable from your current ip address?

Comment: whenever i run react-native run-android the release version is installed. apart from debug version. and for that node js server is not loading. and I am unable to debug the app.